# How to tar a file whose name starts with -

Tags: tar

I want to tar a file whose name id : `-i_jkhv34`

but I am getting an error :

```
tar: invalid option -- '_'
```

is there any way to do so?

Comment: Rename the file maybe?

Comment: Try escaping the `-` using ``\`` example `tar ... \-i_jkhv34`

Comment: Try --, in some versions this will work.

Comment: I don't have control on file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to prevent `tar` from seeing a parameter beginning with `-`

```
tar cf foo ./-i_jkhv34
```

(assuming you want the archive to be named `foo`).

Backslash (`\`) will only be seen by the shell, not by `tar`.

Some implementations of `tar` provide other ways to specify filenames (there *is* no standard for `tar`, by the way).  For instance, GNU `tar` provides a [-T option](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC107) for specifying filenames in a file.  The [`bsdtar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC107) program also does this.

Comment: yeah only option that i find is appending "./"  with file name.